# Convert from Name of Bean and Name of Property to the property in JSP

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I have a been called “**FooOneBean**” and that has a number of properties, one of which is “**fooOnePropA**’ which is a list of **Foo** objects.

In a Java Controller, this bean is set in the request as follows:

```
request.setAttibute(“FooOneBean”, FooOneBean.instance());
```

Normally, this can be used in a JSP to display the dropdown as follows:

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="elementName" />

<c:set var=”dropdown” value=”${FooOneBean.fooOnePropA}” />  <!—Name of the bean and property hard-coded here -- >

<form:select path="${elementName}" id="${elementName}">
<form:options items="${dropdown}" itemLabel="displayName" itemValue="code" /> 
</form:select>
```

However, what we have is a very generic JSP that should be able to display the dropdown based on the String name of the bean and property set in the JSP. The name of the bean or property can change based on how the JSP is invoked.  So,

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="elementName" />
<tiles:importAttribute name="resourceBean" />
<tiles:importAttribute name="resourceList" />


<%--
<c:out value="${resourceBean}" />       <!—Displays “FooOneBean” -->
<c:out value="${resourceList}" />       <!—Displays “fooOnePropA” -->
--%>


<c:set var="beanName" value="${resourceBean}" />
<c:set var="propName" value="${resourceList}" />
<c:set var="dropdown" value="${beanName.propName }" />  

<form:select path="${elementName}" id="${elementName}">
<form:options items="${dropdown}" itemLabel="displayName" itemValue="code" /> 
</form:select>
```

This will fail with the message: '${beanName.propName}' Property 'propName' not found on type java.lang.String

On the otherhand if dropdown is set as:

```
<c:set var="dropdown" value="${beanName}.${propName}" />
```

It fails with the error: Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items

How can this be accomplished in JSP?  I am able to do this using Scriptlets that I want to avoid.

Comment: `requestScope[resourceBean][resourceList]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments from JB Nizet. This can be done as:

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="elementName" />
<tiles:importAttribute name="resourceBean" />
<tiles:importAttribute name="resourceList" />
<c:set var="dropdown" value="${requestScope[resourceBean][resourceList]}”/>

<form:select path="${elementName}" id="${elementName}">
<form:options items="${dropdown}" itemLabel="displayName" itemValue="code" /> 
</form:select>
```